# Is it possible to set the value of Style property of an element by nightwatch.js ? if yes then how?

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, browser-automation, nightwatch.js

I am working with nightwatch.js and i am quite new into this automation testing, i want to set the value into the style property of an element by nightwatch.js, so i am asking, is it possible ? if it is possible then how can we implement it.

I can access the style property values and can check by following nightwatch api command but i couldn't find any way to set the style's value to an element using nightwatch.js

```
browser.expect.element('#main').to.have.css('display').which.equals('block');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Nightwatch Selenium execute protocol](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#execute) to change the style property of an element. With the Selenium execute protocol you can execute arbitrary javascript on the site to be tested.

For example you can use it like this:

```
browser
.execute("document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'block';")
.expect.element('#main').to.have.css('display').which.equals('block');
```

Comment: Fredrik, i will not set but can you please suggest is it possible or not ?

Comment: @AshishJain: I found that the feature you requested in your question is in fact possible to perform using Nightwatch. See my updated answer for how to do this.