# Unable to highlight web element using nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to highlight a web element with some color but unable to achieve that. I've tried using client.execute(), client.executeAsync() methods by setting 'style' attribute to web element but unable to highlight an element as expected and test runs without any errors.

Below is my code.

client.execute(function(){
element.style.backgroundColor = "red"; })

Is there any possibility to highlight an element as selenium does. If so, please provide code/process to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the value of Style property of an element by nightwatch.js ? if yes then how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648278/is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-style-property-of-an-element-by-nightwatch-js)

Answer (score 0):

The element probably need to be passed as argument (not tested):

```
client.execute(function(target){
  target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}, [element]);
```