# Night watch change value of textContent or innerHTML

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

I have the following markup and I need to be able to change the values of the textContent for these items:

```
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Jamie</div>
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Hutber</div>
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Stackoverflow</div>
```

I know how to change values for input fields, but currently don't know how to do text, maybe with a custom command?

**For inputs**

```
  .setValue('.someSelector', 'anewString')
```

Comment: Maybe with [execute](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34658603/1641941)

Comment: Ye HMR I had thought about execute and its certainly a very real options and then assert the details after I have done it directly in the browser?

Comment: I'd think so, the documentation doesn't mention asynchronous execution and even states it assumes the script you pass is assumed to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable'))
     .forEach(x => x.innerHTML = 'new text')
```

Explanation: 
`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which needs to be transformed to an array with `Array.from` in order to be iterable.

In order to modify text of a `div`, you need to set the `innerHTML` attribute. Please note `innerHTML` can be replaced by `textContent`, refer to W3C docs for more information on the difference.

Comment: How can I run this in NW?

Comment: with [execute](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html), as @HMR mentioned in comment

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the only way to do this is to use `.execute()` and modify DOM from inside the page context.

However, depending on your particular use cases, you may want to use more complex selectors, so I am suggesting to use `querySelector()` for that.

In addition, you can also create a shortcut for this operation as shown below:

```
module.exports = {
  'Test': function(client) {
    client
      .url('http://some.url')
      .execute(setElementValue, ['table.selector > .child-selector', 'new value'])
      .end();
  }
};

function setElementValue(selector, value) {
  document.querySelector(selector).textContent = value;
}
```

You might as well create a custom command for that, so you'll be able to reuse it in other tests and make your code look well:

```
// ./lib/custom-commands/setElementValue.js

exports.command = function(selector, value) {
  this.execute(function(selector, value) {
    document.querySelector(selector).textContent = value;
  }, [selector, value]);

  return this;
};

// Test case

client
  .url('http://some.url')
  .setElementValue('table.selector > .child-selector', 'new value')
  .end();
```

Don't forget to point Nightwatch to the directory where you keep your custom commands, by setting `custom_commands_path` property of config file.